# .NET execute a ConsoleApplication before build (including its assembly) from within the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Scenario:

- 1 solution
- ConsoleApplication project
- Other multiple projects

The problem, ConsoleApplication must be built to generate it's assembly (.exe) in order to basically , run..

other projects are dependent on the generated files from the ConsoleApplication, 
is it possible to execute the console application on a pre build event or some other creative solution before building the rest of the projects?

if so, would be nice to have some information regarding that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a Post-Build step to your ConsoleApplication that executes the application and change the build order so that the ConsoleApplication is build first.

The Post-Build step would simply contain a `$(TargetPath)` and to change the build order right click on your solution and select `Project Build Order..`. Here for every other project in the solution you set ConsoleApplication as a dependency

Comment: Another question if you dont mind, how can I add the files generated to my solution explorer after the post build process?

Comment: Well you could simply add them by right clicking the `Project -> Add -> Existing Item...`

Comment: meant, programatically , since the files are being generated and their names can change after every build, all I have is the folder and the wildcard option on all files *.cs

Comment: Manually editing the project file to use a `<Compile Include="*.cs" />` **might** work but I guess it would be better if you create a new question so others may help